# How to read lines from file asynchronously and work with them in gather?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles

I'm trying to replace list of generated numbers with asynchronously reading them from file. How can I do it right?

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep
import aiofiles


async def read_file():
    async with aiofiles.open('test.txt', mode='rb') as f:
        async for line in f:
            yield line


async def main(k):
    print(k)
    await sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_group = 3
    list_objects = list()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

    loop = get_event_loop()

    # TODO How to correctly replace list_objects with read_file()
    list_func = [main(x) for x in list_objects]

    run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
    for rg in run_groups:
        loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```

I tried different options but none of them work. My goal is to asynchronously read lines from file and work with them.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Using async here makes little sense to me. Reading a disk file is an I/O operation that returns practically "immediately". There are no significant wait times during which something else could be done. Anyway, as a solution I would try to create a file based `ReadTransport` for the `asyncio.StreamReader`. It's just an idea I didn't try. The docs discourages to mess with these low-level classes.

Answer (score 1):

As VPfB pointed

- Using `asyncio` not seems usable in the case since jumping to the next line would be in instance so there won't be enough time for other coroutines to get started.
- Other implementation we can do is read file over different places using coroutines/task but since we don't know how many lines are there in file until we read it completely we cannot run multiple task reading files over different points in file.

```py
import time

from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep
import aiofiles


# async generator
async def read_file():
    async with aiofiles.open('test.txt', mode='rb') as f:
        async for line in f:
            yield line

# async coroutines
async read(g):
    for line in g:
        print(line)

# async def main(k):
#    print(k)
#    await sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # count_group = 3
    # list_objects = list()

    # for i in range(1, 11):
    #    list_objects.append(i)

    loop = get_event_loop()

    # TODO How to correctly replace list_objects with read_file()
    # list_func = [main(x) for x in list_objects]

    # run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
    # for rg in run_groups:
    #    loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
    start = time.perf_counter()
    loop.run_until_complete(read(read_file()))
    print(time.perf_counter() - start) # 0.002 approx
```

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
with open('test.txt') as f:
   line = f.readline()
   while line:
       print(line)
       line = f.readline()
print(time.perf_counter() - start) # 0.0002 approx
```

**Note:** Include code performance for reference

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, gather, sleep
import aiofiles

@asyncio.coroutine
def read_line(f):
    while True:
       data = f.readline()
       if data:
           return data
       yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

@asyncio.coroutine
def read_file():
    with open('test.txt', mode  = "r") as f:
        while True:
            line = yield from read_line(f)
            print('Got: {!r}'.format(line))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_group = 3
    list_objects = list()

    for i in range(1, 11):
        list_objects.append(i)

    loop = get_event_loop()

    list_func = [read_file(x) for x in list_objects]

    run_groups = [list_func[i:i + count_group] for i in range(0, len(list_func), count_group)]
    for rg in run_groups:
        loop.run_until_complete(gather(*rg))
```

Comment: "@coroutine" decorator is deprecated since Python 3.8, use "async def" instead. File read mode 'r' is not suitable for me.